# Unable to use package - TCL 9.0 on windows & tcllib1.20

Tags: tcl

Hello and sorry for my poor English,

I have compiled TCL from source with visual studio 2019 under windows 10, and it is in directory :

```
F:\Developpement\TCL\tcl
```

The version seems to be 9.0 as when i type `puts $tcl_version` I got :

> 9.0

But it is strange because the source I have downloaded is `tcl8610-src` ...

After that, I have installed `tcllib1.20` with the provided `installer.tcl` file. Now I have the directory `F:\Developpement\TCL\tcl\lib` which look like :

[image]

In the directory `F:\Developpement\TCL\tcl\lib\tcllib1.20` I have the `pkgIndex.tcl` file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CCUbPhtHV5ISSsFUVNrv7zwdBciNFe4e/view?usp=sharing

When I launch tclsh.exe under windows, and I use the command `package require sha256` i got an error :

> can't find package sha256

As my auto_path was and I don't know if the process of finding package is recursive or not :

> F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib/tcl9.0 F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib

I tried to insert the directory `F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib/tcllib1.20` in my auto_path by doing `set auto_path [linsert $auto_path 0 F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib/tcllib1.20]` I got :

> F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib/tcllib1.20
> F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib/tcl9.0 F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib

So I think it seems correct...

But if I try again `package require sha256` I still got the same error :

> can't find package sha256

I am looking on forum for few hours now and dont resolve my problem... If someone can help me ... ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: try : `set auto_path [linsert $auto_path 0 F:/Developpement/TCL/tcl/lib/tcllib1.20/modules]` for me I have this path: `tcllib1.20/modules` and all packages are in this folder

Comment: I've no idea where you got that from. Tcl 9 is still very much in alpha. 8.6 is the production release (and 8.7 is the alpha that is more highly compatible with 8.6).

Comment: Sources for the current release (8.6.10) can be downloaded from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/8.6.10/

Comment: Hi, I download the package from here :   https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8610-src.zip... I will try to reinstall the version from : https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/8.6.10/ thanks. Will try also what Mkn said and tell you if I found a solution. Thanks agian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that works now, I installed TCL 8.6.10 and I got 8.6 verison when typing "puts tcl_version".
I also add the '/module' to the directory path.

Thanks a lot.